# Como capturar tempo de uso de aplicativos instalados no Android

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber como poderia capturar o tempo de uso de todos aplicativos instalados no Android. Há alguns apps que façam isso na Play Store.
Andei fazendo varias buscas e descobri que há um código que você pode digitar e aparece uma lista de programas, porém não consigo tratar o resultado.

Alguém saberia como eu poderia fazer isso? Seja tratando o resultado do "easter Egg", ou até mesmo um serviço para detectar o tempo de uso.

Comment: Vc quer dizer tempo de uso (que o usuário passa dentro do app) ou tempo desde que o app foi instalado?

Answer (score 1):

Não existe uma forma oficial de se fazer isso, através do SDK do Android.
Há uma resposta, em inglês, para uma pergunta similar: [How to Track App Usage in Android? How to detect when an activity is launched?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012361/how-to-track-app-usage-in-android-how-to-detect-when-an-activity-is-launched)

Mas resumindo a resposta, você pode ficar fazendo pooling no [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html), mas isso seria bem ruim do ponto de vista de bateria. E o rastreamento só vai funcionar após uma execução do seu app.

Se quiser essa informação na tela do telefone, você pode digitar o código `*#*#4636#*#*` e ir em (Testing -> Usage statistics). Além disso, também é possível ter uma informação parecida com o que você quer indo na parte de consumo de bateria.